# Maintain previous Page values and selected controls states on Browser back button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iis

I'have developed asp.net project in .NET 4.0, everything is fine, **except when user clicks the browser back button, old page is loosing all the control's selected states** (eg Checkboxlist, dropdownlist etc.) **and values entered in textboxes**.

*"I tried to resolved by putting session variables, Before redirect i'm saving everything in session and, when user goes to previous page, i'm validating the session state and rebinding everything. BUT it seems to be costly operations."*

is there any other/near-around solution.

(Please note that i'm using ajax componets and update panels.)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can save your form state by using cookies and reading them again after detecting the history.back
Or alternatively please check this jQuery plugin
http://tkyk.github.io/jquery-history-plugin/#documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the form elements in ASP.NET Viewstate(clientside). Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx)
Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but unfortunately it will not work, may be because of ajax update panel, or the page life-cycle event model, one more thing asp.net controls are generating dynamically